# Synchronous method vs Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, synchronous, thread-sleep

I can't understand the difference between `Thread.Sleep()` and *synchronous* methods. Please explain..

Is synchronous method in C#  is similar to `Thread.Sleep()`?.

Comment: This question is... odd. If someone told you this, you should probably stop getting programming advice from them.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Please try clearing up what you actually mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, other than `Thread.Sleep` is a synchronous method.

A **synchronous method** is one where the entirety of their functionality happens before returning control to the caller.

`Thread.Sleep` is a function which causes the executing thread to block for the specified number of milliseconds (not exactly, but close due to the CPU thread scheduler). It executes synchronously and wouldn't be as useful in an asynchronous method.

However, saying they are the same thing would be a misnomer, as there are plenty of synchronous methods that are not `Thread.Sleep` and do not use it either.